# Rails add relative record after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app which contains the following models:

```
class Costproject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :costquestion, :dependent => :destroy

class Costquestion < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :costproject
```

When I create a `costproject`, I want one related `costquestion` created.

In the `cosproject` model, I tried:

```
after_save :create_costquestion
  protected
def create_costquestion
  self.costquestion.build
end
```

But, self seems to be nil - why is that?

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `self` isn't `nil`, `costquestion` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [other points out the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583049/rails-add-relative-record-after-save/30583164#comment49235994_30583049), why the error, I wouldn't re-iterate it. And here is a solution you can use :

```
def create_costquestion
  self.build_costquestion
  self.save!
end
```

Check the [helper methods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) comes with this associations from Rails.

**Note**: your method `create_costquestion` is what Rails already created for you by its *magic*. So, better give it a new name which shouldn't overwrite the out of the box method.

Edit: A little change to save the child while saving parent.

```
class Costproject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :costquestion, :dependent => :destroy, autosave: true
```

Comment: While equivalent to the other answer, using the built-in helper methods are usually a better choice.

Comment: Doesn't `self.save` save the costproject and not the costquestion?

Comment: I get `execution expired`

Comment: @Reddirt change the method name to like `_create_costquestion`.. and try,

Comment: This worked `    costquestion = self.build_costquestion
    costquestion.save!`

Answer (score 1):

`costquestion` is nil this point. You're pointing to a relationship that doesn't yet exist. If you changed this to be something like this you should be ok:

```
def create_costquestion
  costquestion = Costquestion.build #does this save?
  self.costquestion = costquestion
  self.save
end
```

Comment: You don't have to guess; (a) the error message is regarding the call to `build`, which isn't being called on the `Costproject` instance, and (b) `self` cannot be `nil` in an instance method, for obvious reasons.